# How to add speech to text to a JS application?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ibm-watson

I would like to implement speech to text to this application which I have found on github. Its using IBM Watson APIs.
The applications is available here -> https://github.com/IBM/watson-banking-chatbot

But all my attempts did not work so far...
I am using chrome webkit speech recognition for stt since its much better that IBMs tts.

I tried it with the following snippets in the index.html file...

I changed this...

```html
<label for="textInput" class="inputOutline">
          <input id="textInput" class="input responsive-column"
            placeholder="Type something" type="text" value=""
            onkeydown="/*globals CanvasJS */
            ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)">
        </label>
```

to this piece of code...

```html
<label for="textInput" class="inputOutline">
<div id="textInput" class="input responsive-column" type="text" placeholder="Type something" ></div></label>
```

This is the speech recognition part which should send the question by the keyword "ASK"...

```html
<button onclick="startConverting();"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></button>
<script type="text/javascript">



 var r = document.getElementById('textInput');
 function startConverting (){

  if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window){
 var speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
 speechRecognizer.continuous = true;
 speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
 speechRecognizer.lang = 'en-IN';
 speechRecognizer.start();

 var finalTranscripts = '';

 speechRecognizer.onresult = function(event){
          var interimTranscripts = '';
          for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++){
           var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript; 
           transcript.replace("\n", "<br>");
           if(event.results[i].isFinal){
            finalTranscripts += transcript;
           }else{
            interimTranscripts += transcript;
           }}
 

 if(finalTranscripts.includes('two')){
           window.alert('It works');


          }


 if(finalTranscripts.includes('ask')){
           ConversationPanel.send(finalTranscripts, this);


          }         

          r.innerHTML = finalTranscripts + '<span style="color#999' +interimTranscripts + '</span>'; 
 };

 speechRecognizer.onerror = function (event) {

 };



}else {
 r.innerHTML = 'please update google chrome ';
}

 }



</script>
                



        <!--        <button id="speak-btn">Speak</button>-->
        <audio autoPlay="true" id="audio"
               className="audio" 
               controls="controls">
              Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
```

I'm dealing already since a longer time with this problem. I am happy for any kind of help!

Comment: please check this: https://tutorialzine.com/2017/08/converting-from-speech-to-text-with-javascript

Comment: I've checked it but it's unfortunately not thr right thing. Very interesting anyway.